# Placing Canvas on top of another on click

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

The project I'm working on involves having to place layers of rectangles over each other on click. I created a layout with context rectangles inside the canvas with definite positions. Now on click I need to be able to create more layers over each context one after the other with the same positions as the parent `containers`(rectangles) infinite amount of times(they would overlap). Could I achieve this by placing a new canvas over them or a new rectangle and how would I be able to do this?

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/c45hkmn7/4/)

HTML

```html
<canvas id="videoWall" class="videoWallContainer"> 
        <!--<div class="area"></div>-->
     </canvas>  
     <button>
     Click ME
     </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can achieve that by placing a new canvas over old ones, you really don't have to.

Just like an artist's canvas, you can place as many strokes as you like on the same canvas, even in the same position. In fact, you can do all that using the same context.

---

Now to your specific use case, I wasn't quite sure whether you want to paint a new layer over a specific rectangle or over every rectangle. However, I tried to provide a generic solution for both cases.

- The `Paint One` button allows you to paint a rectangle over **one** of the four portions
- The `Paint All` button paints rectangles of the same color over **each** of the four portions
- The `Paint Different Colors` button paints rectangles of **different colors** over the four portions
- The `Test Stack` button paints a smaller rectangle *to reveal a previous rectangle* behind it, thus proving that the layers are actually stacked and not just being replaced each time.

---

Note: I used `layout.fillRect()` instead of `layout.rect()` to make the colors of layers more visible and also save some keystrokes.

---

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Zamorite/2mf6rdkg/2/), just in case.

---

I really hope this helps.
All the best

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("videoWall");
var layout = canvas.getContext("2d");
layout.className = 'layouts';



// Some colors to make each layer distinct
var colors = ['#006d77', '#83c5be', '#edf6f9', '#ffddd2', '#e29578'];

// The positions where our rectangles can be painted on
var args = {
  topLeft: [0, 0, 150, 75],
  topRight: [150, 0, 150, 75],
  bottomLeft: [0, 75, 150, 75],
  bottomRight: [150, 75, 150, 75],
};

// This allows us to create a smaller rectangle and verify that each rectangle is actually stacked on the previous one
var stackTestArgs = [0, 0, 75, 75];



// A function to draw a rectangle using a given context and provided arguments
var drawRect = (ctx, args) => ctx.fillRect(...args);

// A function to get a random color
var getRandomColor = () => colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];



// stack a new layer (with same color) over all rectangles
function paintAll() {
  layout.fillStyle = getRandomColor();

  // loop through all the entries in args and draw a rectangle with the values in the each entry
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(args)) {
    drawRect(layout, value);
  }
}



// stack a new layer (with different color) over all rectangles
function paintAllDifferentColors() {
  // loop through all the entries in args, change the context's fill style and draw a rectangle with the values in the each entry
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(args)) {
    layout.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
    drawRect(layout, value);
  }
}


// stack a new layer over a specific rectangle (default is args.topLeft)
function paintOne(position = args.topLeft) {
  layout.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
  drawRect(layout, position);
}


// stack a smaller layer over the first layer to proof that previous layers are actually beneath the new layers
var testStack = () => paintOne(stackTestArgs);
```

```css
.videoWallContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="videoWall" class="videoWallContainer">
   <!--<div class="area"></div>-->
 </canvas>

<!-- Buttons for updating canvas -->

<button onClick="paintOne()">
   Paint One
 </button>

<button onClick="paintAll()">
   Paint All
 </button>

<button onClick="paintAllDifferentColors()">
   Paint Different Colors
 </button>

<button onClick="testStack()">
   Test Stack
 </button>
```